# Chrome - Android - refresh PWA

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I pushed a new version of my PWA (progressive web application). How can I refresh it on my android/chrome mobile?

I have

*Close all tabs

*Close the browser

*Restart my phone

I still do not have the latest version.

(It works in incognito mode)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to url "chrome://serviceworker-internals/".
2. Find your application.
3. Click "Unregister" button.
4. Refresh your application.

Comment: This is very helpful except I have 100s of entries in the list displayed. Is there a way to search them?

EDIT: nevermind, they are in alphabetical order